# Does から (since/from) have a kanji?

Tags: grammar, kanji, particle-から

I'm just learning about から and まで.

I know many words have kanji forms but are rarely if ever used but I like to learn them anyway as I'm interested in the etymology of words.

I noticed that まで has the kanji 迄 which means (up to/till) in Chinese , pronounced qì.

On a side note the Japanese 迄　seems to have an extra 点 than the Chinese character.

Anyway I can't find any mention of a kanji for から.

Does it have one ? Even a super old and rare long forgotten kanji ?

Comment: 自 and 至 are understood as “from” and “to”, respectively, in some contexts (as in Chinese), but I don’t know of a single case where they are **read** から or まで.

Answer (score 2):

から has a few different meanings. Let's take the following examples.

学校は午前８時１０分から始まる。
The equivalent in Chinese appears to use 開始 (read かいし in Japanese and meaning "start") to convey the idea of starting from a certain point in time.

彼の部屋に明かりがついているから、彼は帰宅したにちがいない。​
Chinese seems to use 所以 (read ゆえん in Japanese and meaning "reason") to convey the idea of "therefore."

１０から２を引くと、８残る。
Chinese appears to use 中 (read なか in Japanese and sometimes meaning "out of") to convey the idea of taking one thing out of another.

よく振ってから使用してください。
Chinese seems to use 前 (read まえ in Japanese and meaning "before") to convey the idea of doing one thing before another.

None of the kanji above appear to have から as an alternative reading, and dictionaries do not list a historical kanji for the particle から as they do for まで.